# Convert video to web format with Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

We've just started using Microsoft Azure, and trying to investigate is it possible to - upload video and convert it to web format automatically.

Maybe someone has already did it and has some experience.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [**Azure Media Services**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/encoding/).

You can encode to adaptive multi-bitrate MP4 with dynamic packaging on top (think MPEG-DASH, HLS, Smooth Streaming).

Encoding via the Azure Portal:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-portal-encode

.NET SDK:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-encode-with-media-encoder-standard

REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-encode-asset

For an event-based approach look at **Azure Functions** with a Blob Trigger. As soon as there's a new source file to be encoded [you can kick off a job](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/media-services-dotnet-functions-integration/).

Comment: Thanks EvilSnobu, It is great service, but can I download the converted video directly by any API? I didn't found this in any doc,

Comment: Sure, should be under the storage account you associated your Azure Media Services instance with. Use the blob storage SDK to download it and the [AssetFile REST call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/assetfile) to get the URL to the blob.

Comment: But I am using this approach, `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-tutorial-with-rest`, I have a video URL, and I want to encode it in mp4, so I can play it on devices or browser, how can I get download url in this case?